# Backbone , changing models attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In a collection i need to set the value to one of attributes, but i cant find the way how do it

```
products.models[i].set({'category.name':'some_value'})
```

the rest api looks like this

```
{
    "category": {
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "Drink", 
        "icon": "staging/main/category/icon-drinks.png"
    }, 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Sugar54", 
    "dashboard": 1, 
    "last_buy": "2013-10-02", 
    "price": "102", 
    "buy_period": 7
},
```

How do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex nested models, I suggest you take a look at [BackboneRelational](http://backbonerelational.org/).
Otherwise in your case, you should be fine with

```
products.models[i].get('category').name = 'some_value';
```

supposing that `category` is a normal object.